# Accessing a class member of pointer type to a nested class

Tags: c++

I have a string class, with a nested struct in it `Srep` and a pointer of that type `rep` and a class `Cref` as its public member.

```
class String {
struct Srep; //representation
Srep* rep;

public:
class Cref;
//...
}
```

Now inside my member functions whenever I use `rep` there occurs an error `pointer to incomplete class type "String::Srep" is not allowed`

```
void write (int i , char c){
  rep = rep->get_own_copy();
  rep->s[i];
}

Cref operator [] (int i){
  check (i) ;
  return Cref(*this,i);
}
```

However somewhere below the `String class` definition I have defined both the classes `Srep` and `Cref`

```
struct String::Srep {
char* s; //pointer to elements
int sz;  //number of characters
int n ; //number of reference

Srep (int nsz, const char* p){
    n = 1;
    sz = nsz;
    s = new char[sz + 1]; // one more for '\0'
    strcpy(s,p);

}

~Srep(){
    delete [] s;
}

Srep* get_own_copy (){
    if(n == 1) return this;
    n--; //think
    return new Srep(sz,s);
}

void assign (int nsz , const char* p){
    if (sz != nsz){
        delete [] s;
        sz = nsz;
        s = new char (sz + 1);
       }
    strcpy(s,p);
   }
private:
 Srep(const Srep&);
 Srep& operator = (const Srep&);
 };
```

So, how can I access a member of class with the pointer type of a nested class?

Comment: At the point the code is compiled, the class must be defined. You're using it *before* defining it. Just move your code.

Comment: What you are describing is known as the [Private Implementation (Pimpl) idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). You just need to define the inner class before the code that is accessing its members.

Comment: doesn't answer my question